# How to use linked DateTime using Bootstrap DateTimePicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I have a form which contains Departure date and return date. And I want to set the minimum date in the return date field is the date of selected departure date. I already put the id in div tag or input tag, but nothing worked. Do you know why?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Departure<span class="required"> *</span></label>
    <div class="input-group date form_datetime col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" id="res_departure1" data-link-field="dtp_input1">
        <input class="form-control pull-right" size="16" type="text" value="" readonly required>
        <input type="hidden" id="dtp_input1"  name="res_departure" value="" />
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Return<span class="required"> *</span></label>
    <div class="input-group date form_datetime col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" id="res_return1" data-link-field="dtp_input2">
        <input class="form-control pull-right"  size="16" type="text" value="" readonly required>
        <input type="hidden" id="dtp_input2" name="res_return" value="" />
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>
      </div>
</div>
```

This is my js

```
$('.form_datetime').datetimepicker({
    //language:  'fr',
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii",
    autoclose: true,
    todayBtn: true,
    startDate: new Date
});

$("#res_departure1").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    $('#res_return1').data("DateTimePicker").setMinDate(e.date);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#res_departure1').datetimepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    var departureDate = ev.date;
    $('#res_return1').datetimepicker('setStartDate', departureDate);
});

$('#res_return1').datetimepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    var returnDate = ev.date;
    $('#res_departure1').datetimepicker('setEndDate', returnDate);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of your code

```
$('.form_datetime').datetimepicker({
    //language:  'fr',
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii",
    autoclose: true,
    todayBtn: true,
    startDate: new Date()
});

$("#res_departure1").on("dp.change", function (e) {
   $('#res_return1').data('DateTimePicker').minDate(new Date(e.timeStamp));
});
```

Comment: It is still not working. I still can choose the return date before the selected departure date

Comment: $('#res_return1').data('DateTimePicker').minDate(e.date);  try $('#res_return1').data('DateTimePicker').minDate(new Date(e.timeStamp));

Comment: It is still not working. There is no error, but not working too. I have tried it both with setMinDate and minDate

Answer (score 0):

Because when you are talking about date only, then better to use `datepicker` on `jQuery ui` library, and then you can use the `onSelect` event of the departure date and then set the min date of return field.

```
  onSelect: function(selectedDate)
  {
    $('#return').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate);
  }
```

[you can check the working fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/stdeepak22/b49ky1by/)

Comment: actually I need the time too. That is why I choose dateTimePicker. :)